# Panel administrativo, creación de usuarios por usuario administrador en Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, crud

Estoy pasando el registro de usuario que tiene laravel por defecto para que pueda hacerlo un usuario administrador. Cuando intento crear un usuario me pide confirmacion de contraseña a pesar de que la ingreso, igualmente con el editado de los usuarios.

Adjunto el código de controlador de usuarios:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\UserStoreRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UserUpdateRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;



class UserController extends Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $users = User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate();

    return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
     return view('admin.users.create');

     return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(UserStoreRequest $request)
{
    //validacion
    $user = User::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('users.edit', $user->id)
        ->with('info', 'Usuario creado con exito');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    return view('admin.users.show', compact('user'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    return view('admin.users.edit', compact('user'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(UserUpdateRequest $request, $id)
{
    $User = User::find($id);

    $User->fill($request->all())->save();

     return redirect()->route('users.edit', $user->id)
        ->with('info', 'Usuario editado con exito');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id)->delete();

    return back()->with('info', 'Eliminado correctamente');
}
}
```

El código de la vista de creado de usuarios:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Crear usuario
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'users.store']) !!}

                        @include('admin.users.partials.form')

                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

El código de la vista de editado de usuarios:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Editar usuario
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {!! Form::model($user, ['route' => ['users.update', $user->id], 
                    'method' => 'PUT']) !!}

                        @include('admin.users.partials.form')

                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y el form que utilizo tanto para crear como para editar:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
{{ Form::label('name', 'Nombre de usuario') }}
{{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
{{ Form::label('email', 'Correo') }}
{{ Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'email']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
{{ Form::label('password', 'Contraseña') }}
{{ Form::password('password', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'password']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
{{ Form::label('password-confirm', 'Confirmacion de contraseña') }}
{{ Form::password('password-confirm', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'password-confirm']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::submit('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary']) }}
</div>
```

Si utilizo este form puedo crear el usuario pero tiene dos detalles. No me encripta la contraseña y cuando voy a editar al usuario no me aperecen sus datos guardados

```
 <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Name</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">E-Mail Address</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Confirm Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Register
                            </button>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDIT1:** Agrego el codigo de UserStoreRequest

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UserStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ];
}
}
```

Y el de UserUpdateRequest:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UserUpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed', 
    ];
}
}
```

**EDIT2:** Pude crear los usuarios con la contreseña encriptada agregando lo siguiente al modelo user:

```
 public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
 {   
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
 }
```

Ademas de modificar el codigo de form a lo siguiente:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
{{ Form::label('name', 'Nombre de usuario') }}
{{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
{{ Form::label('email', 'Correo') }}
{{ Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'email']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
{{ Form::label('password', 'Contraseña') }}
{{ Form::password('password', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'password']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
{{ Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Confirmacion de contraseña') }}
{{ Form::password('password_confirmation', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'password_confirmation']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::submit('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary']) }}
</div>
```

Sin embargo si entro a editar al usuario y no hago ningún cambio y le doy guardar me dice que el correo ya existe y que la contraseña es necesitada. Debería de guardar al usuario sin ningún cambio.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el contenido de UserUpdateRequest

Comment: Si tienes un nuevo error, ya se sale del alcance inicial de esta pregunta, deberías formular una nueva pregunta y tal vez aceptar la respuesta dado que al parecer te sirvió para solucionar el problema planteado inicialmente.

Answer (score 1):

Según la documentación de Laravel, el campo que "confirma" la clave o algún otro campo debe llevar el sufijo "_confirmation".

Dicho campo (actualmente "password-confirm") quedaría así:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
{{ Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Confirmacion de contraseña') }}
{{ Form::password('password_confirmation', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'password_confirmation']) }}
</div>
```